# Remove duplicate rows but retain all possible values of second column

Tags: sql, oracle

Say that I've got a table with two columns and following values:

```
C1 | C2
------- 
a1   b1 
a1   b2 
a1   b3
a2   b1 
a2   b2
a2   b3
a3   b1
a3   b2
a3   b3
```

I would like to remove all rows with duplicate values for C1, but in such a way that the remaining rows, have all the different values for C2 retained. So in this case the result would have to be:

```
C1 | C2
------- 
a1   b1 
a2   b2
a3   b3
```

And not something like:

```
C1 | C2
------- 
a1   b1 
a2   b1
a3   b1
```

Comment: will it always be like this? each C1 has all the values in C2 and the opposit?

Comment: Does it matter if you gonna retain combination of a1-b1 ... or it can be a2-b1?

Comment: @Yossi, no there could be another row in there a4 | c4 with none of the other values for example.

Comment: @Veljko89, it does not matter. Both are ok.

Comment: What result would you expect if there were an un-equal number of items in each list. I.e. add a `a3   b4` row to your data set.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i would go in that case, using T-SQL that is

```
if object_ID('tempdb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp

create table #Temp (c1 nvarchar(5), c2 nvarchar(5))

insert into #Temp (c1, c2)
values 
('a1','b1'),
('a1','b2'), 
('a1','b3'),
('a2','b1'),
('a2','b2'),
('a2','b3'),
('a3','b1'),
('a3','b2'),
('a3','b3')

if object_ID('tempdb..#Temp2') is not null drop table #Temp2
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c2 order by c2) [Num] into #Temp2 from #Temp t1

delete from #Temp2 where Num != 1

select * from #Temp2
```

As you don't care of combination ... you'll get distinct values

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a fully reliable way to do what you want in SQL.  I suspect that the actual problem might be equivalent to a graph problem that is NP or NP-complete.

One approximation is to choose a random row for each value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by c1 order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This, of course, has no guarantees.  But it at least opens the possibility of getting the rows you want.

A second method works if you have all combinations (such as in your example).  If so, you can construct the rows from the values:

```
select t1.c1, t2.c2
from (select least(count(distinct c1), count(distinct c2)) as cd from t) cross join
     (select distinct c1, rownum as rn from t) t1 join
     (select distinct c2, rownum as rn from t) t2
     on mod(t1.rn, cd) = mod(t1.rn, cd);
```

However, this assumes that the result pair is actually in a row.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is ridiculously complicated, but I believe it does the trick!  It could be rather slow for large data sets...

```
with selector as
( select rownum-1 as setnum
  from dual
  connect by level <= power(2,(select count(*) from my_table))
), /* This generates the integers 0..(2^n)-1 where n is number of rows in table */
data as
( select c1, c2, row_number() over (order by c1, c2) as rn
  from my_table
), /* This assigns each row in the table a row number 1..n */
cj as
( select setnum, c1, c2
  from selector cross join data
  where bitand(setnum, power(2,rn-1)) = power(2,rn-1)
 ), /* This generates all the possible sets of 1-n rows. 
       The rows in the set are determined by the bits of the setnum value
       e.g. setnum 5 (101 in binary) contains rows 1 and 4 */
set_sizes as
 ( select setnum, count(*) cnt from cj
   group by setnum
   having count(distinct c1) = (select count(distinct c1) from my_table)
   and count(distinct c2) = (select count(distinct c2) from my_table)
), /* This determines the number of rows in each set AND excludes sets that
      don't include all the c1 and c2 values */
one_set as
( select min(setnum) minsetnum from set_sizes
  where cnt = (select min(cnt) from set_sizes)
) /* This selects one of the sets that has the smallest number of rows */
select c1, c2 from cj
where setnum = (select minsetnum from one_set)
order by 1
```

It does this:

1. generates all possible sets of rows from the table
2. filters out those that do not contain all c1 values and all c2 values
3. finds the smallest sets from these
4. Arbitrarily chooses one of these smallest sets and returns its data

If anyone can suggest better (more meaningful) names for my with-clause subqueries, please do!